# Which one is correct: "was/were dead" or "is/are dead" years ago?

Tags: tenses, be, past-vs-present

What are the differences between “was/were dead” and “is/are dead”?

For example,

> Osama is/was dead years ago.

Are they interchangeable?

Comment: Hello. Is this particular to *dead*? Do you know which of these is right: *He is bald/blue/happy/married years ago* or *he was bald/blue/happy/married years ago*? Do you know what tense *is* is? Do you think it ever makes logical sense to say that something *is* years ago?

Comment: This question is very basic. Please consider supporting our proposal for [English language learners](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/41665/english-language-learners)

Comment: Because @RoaringFish wants me to [teach](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/3006) rather than downvote, I'll teach.  Please don't ask the question, "Are they interchangable?" "Are they interchangeable?" is virtually unanswerable, because rarely is language interchangeable in all contexts. (For example, _stop_ and _halt_ may be synonyms, but I'd never say, "We need a new halt sign at that intersection").  It would be better to ask something more like, "Is there any context where these could be interchangeable?" or, "Could these be regarded as synonyms in certain instances?"

Comment: `is` = present / future; `was` = past.

Answer (score 3):

Actually the construction "was/is dead years ago" doesn't make sense. The correct way of saying that is:

> Osama's dead; he died many years ago.

Answer (score 3):

**Edit -** "Osama was dead years ago" is fine.  "Osama is dead years ago" is NOT fine, as it uses the present tense in a past context.

However, the normal way of saying this is

> Osama has been dead for many years.

Answer (score 1):

*Years ago* ties the event to a certain time in the past. When that is the case, the past tense is required and the normal way of expressing the thought would be *Osama died years ago*. *Was dead* doesn’t work because it describes a state rather than event, but you could say something like *Osama was dead long before I was born.*