# "dead brother's grandson" VS "passed-away brother's grandson"

Tags: differences, adjectives, kinship-terms, euphemisms

One is

> **dead** brother's grandson (and) **dead** sister's grandson.

The other  is

> **passed-away** brother's grandson (and) **passed-away** sister's grandson.

They come from part of a novel which I'm translating for study.
Which one is better? I've heard that *pass away* is more indirect and *dead* sounds a bit harsh. I don't know which one sounds better or more suitable.

Comment: We can't tell you which is "better or more suitable" without knowing the context. If you're talking to somebody about a recently deceased relative, "passed away" is probably better. If you're talking to a scientist about a corpse, then "dead" is probably better. It all depends on the context.

Comment: Another option might be _late_, which means the same, as in _my late grandfather_.

Comment: related: ['Expired' or 'Passed away'?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/55146/expired-or-passed-away) and [Which is better: “was dead” ;“died”;“has passed away” in my case?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/114991/which-is-better-was-dead-died-has-passed-away-in-my-case)

Comment: This needs more context. When did the deceased person die? Whose relatives are we talking about? For example I might say *"my grandson's father **has recently passed away/died**"* OR *"his dead daughter's son"* i.e. if the person is speaking about a grandfather's grandson whose daughter (the child's mother) is dead.

Answer (score 11):

The expression [*to pass away*](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/american_english/pass?q=pass%20away#pass__15) is rarely, if ever, used as a compound adjective as you have done, i.e. *passed-away*. The current construction with *dead* sounds awkward because it is missing pronouns, e.g. *my*, *his*, etc. A more [idiomatic](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/american_english/idiomatic) alternative for your example is [*late*](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/american_english/late), and I quote from the 3rd [adjective] definition in [Oxford Dictionaries](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/american_english/late):

> **(the/one's late)**  (Of a specified person) no longer alive:
> *the late William Jennings Bryan*
> *her late husband’s grave*

So, assuming the first personal pronoun (*my*) is appropriate, two possible translations for your passage might be:

- *One is my dead brother's grandson and the other is my dead sister's grandson.*
- *One is my **late** brother's grandson and the other is my **late** sister's grandson.*

Answer (score 1):

It would be ungrammatical and very awkward-sounding to say, "One is passed-away brother's grandson and the other is passed-away sister's grandson."

That said, I cannot opine as to which term is "better" sounding. The dictionary definitions of both terms reach the same conclusion---cessation of existence---though each term also carries different connotations and “emotional overtones": "dead" is, for some people, perhaps, more clinical, emphatic, final, and ... blunt; while, "passed away" is euphemistic, less direct and final, and perhaps provides some emotional “cushion” to what can be a traumatic event for those who are still “living,” and “left behind.”

> **Dead** *adjective*:
>
> **1**. no longer alive.
>
> • "a dead body"
>
> *synonyms*: passed on/away, expired, departed, gone, no more; 
>   late, lost, lamented;
>
> Merriam-Webster [**dead**](https://www.google.com/search?newwindow=1&site=&source=hp&q=dead+definition&oq=dead+de&gs_l=hp.1.0.0i20j0j0i20j0l4j0i10j0l2.5802.8362.0.15178.8.8.0.0.0.0.215.1040.0j7j1.8.0.msedr...0...1c.1.62.hp..1.7.823.0.TcbyJ3QfYx0)
>
> **Pass away** *intransitive verb*
>
> **1**: to go out of existence
>
> **2**: die
>
> Merriam-Webster [**pass away**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pass%20away)

Answer (score 1):

*Passed-away*, as other people have pointed out, is not a phrase in common use.

*Dead* suggests someone who is either dead in front of you or dead for centuries.

I would say

- "the grandson of one's late brother"
- "the grandson of one's deceased brother"

I would recommend against "one's deceased brother's grandson", because it leaves it faintly unclear exactly *who* is dead: the brother or his grandson.

Comment: +1: Good point regarding possible ambiguity here. Although, it seemed fairly clear to me that it was the subject's sister and brother that were deceased. I'd sooner use *brother's late grandson/sister's late grandson* if this wasn't the case!

Comment: @JimiOke, I don't think it is _actually_ ambiguous, it just isn't 100% clear, so there is that momentarily delay while the reader thinks about it.

Answer (score -1):

Both mean the exact same thing, only the latter is a euphemism.

Therefore, when determining which is more appropriate to use, the context is what matters.

In casual situations, the euphemism "passed-away" might be the better option.